# JAX: JIT compatible sparse matrix slicing

Tags: python, numpy, jax

I have a boolean sparse matrix that I represent with row indices and column indices of `True` values.

```py
import numpy as np
import jax
from jax import numpy as jnp
N = 10000
M = 1000
X = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(N, M)) == 0  # data setup
rows, cols = np.where(X == True)
rows = jax.device_put(rows)
cols = jax.device_put(cols)
```

I want to get a column slice of the matrix like `X[:, 3]`, but just from rows indices and column indices.

I managed to do that by using `jnp.isin` like below, but the problem is that this is not JIT compatible because of the data-dependent shaped array `rows[cols == m]`.

```py
def not_jit_compatible_slice(rows, cols, m):
  return jnp.isin(jnp.arange(N), rows[cols == m])
```

I could make it JIT compatible by using `jnp.where` in the three-argument form, but this operation is much slower than the previous one.

```py
def jit_compatible_but_slow_slice(rows, cols, m):
  return jnp.isin(jnp.arange(N), jnp.where(cols == m, rows, -1))
```

Is there any fast and JIT compatible solution to acheive the same output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a bit better than the first answer by using the `mode` argument of `set()` to drop out-of-bound indices, eliminating the final slice:

```py
out = jnp.zeros(N, bool).at[jnp.where(cols==3, rows, N)].set(True, mode='drop')
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the implementation below returns the same output much faster, and it’s JIT compatible.

```py
def slice(rows, cols, m):
  res = jnp.zeros(N + 1, dtype=bool)
  res = res.at[jnp.where(cols == m, rows, -1)].set(True)
  return res[:-1]
```